# How do I Mapout 1D object value into 2D object property value C# EF6 WCF Is there a better or simpler way than what I am doing?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf

I am using Entity Framework V6, WCF, and Windowsforms:
I am trying to map out a 1D object value to property of an Collection of MyObjectDTO which makes it a 3D (maybe that is 2D)  object space (Defined basically as Rows, Columns ) Datatables came to my mind but entity framework has entities not tables!

I have an array of Items[1..n] returned to me from a 3rd party component and each element of that array represents a property in my DTO and can be 1 or even 2000 items.

I am trying to map that Items[x] to a property of a given DTO in collection KeyedList 
The Items[n] has an object KeyID which I defined as a class called KeyID with 3 properties Parent, UniqueID, PropertyName - which I set when it is instantiated - for its lifetime (basically as long as my application will run with out crashing) it must remain the same!

I have the following code but I am not sure if this is the correct approach, the long approach or the wrong approach.
So I would like some serious experts to look at the code and tell me if there is a better way or a simpler way to do this.

```
// This is only one of the DTO's could be different DTO's

class MyDTOobject
{

   bool Property1 {get; set;}
   bool Property2 {get; set;}
   int Property3 {get; set;}
   string Property4 {get; set;}
   float Property5 {get; set;}
   string Property6 {get; set;}

}

KeyID
{
 Guid Parent {get; set;}
 Guid UniqueID {get; set;}
 string PropertyName {get; set;}
}

KeyedList<MyDTO> MyDTOList KeyedList<MyDTO>

// ItemValues[] are 1 to n not always the same or the same items.
OtherGuysObjectsChanged(ItemValues[] items)
{

for(int i=0; i < items.Length; i++)
{

// this an object items.KeyID 
   keyID =  (KeyID)items[i].KeyID;
   MyInstanceDTOobject = MyDTOList[keyID.Parent];
   if(MyInstanceDTOobject != null)
   {
    var setvalues  = SetValues[items[i].KeyID.PropertyName];
    setvalues(MyInstanceDTOobject, items[i].Value);
    MyDTOList[keyID.Parent] = MyInstanceDTOobject;
   }

}


// Call to thread to push this stuff to WCF Clients. 
// Maybe even every .250 seconds would like to transform my list into simple list if I need to .
// Call to thread for my entityFramework stuff and take that list of DTO's 
// that has now changed and update a db .

}


Dictionary<string,Action<MyDTOobject, object> SetValues = new Dictionary<string,Action<MyDTOobject, object>()
{
    {"Property1", (m,v) => m.Property1 = (bool)v.value},
    {"Property2", (m,v) => m.Property2 = (bool)v.value},
    {"Property3", (m,v) => m.Property3 = (int)v.value},
    {"Property4", (m,v) => m.Property4 = (string)v.value},
    {"Property5", (m,v) => m.Property5 = (float)v.value},
    {"Property6", (m,v) => m.Property6 = (string)v.value} ;
}


// KeyedList<T>
// Basically I found an IList implementation on the web and Modified it with the addition of a dictionary 
//- I am hoping to be able push this list to a WCF client and update a DataGridview with it.


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text;

namespace Utility.Collections
{
    public class KeyedList<T> : IList<T>
    {
        internal List<T> _innerList;

        private List<T> InnerList
        {
            get
            {
                return _innerList;
            }
            set
            {
                _innerList = value;
                OnInnerListChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }

        public event EventHandler InnerListChanged;

        /// <summary>
        /// Inner List Changed Event
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        protected virtual void OnInnerListChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            var handler = InnerListChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, e);
            }

        }

        private IEnumerable<T> _keyedLoader;

        internal IEnumerable<T> KeyedLoader
        {
            get
            {
                return _keyedLoader;
            }
            set
            {
                _keyedLoader = value;
            }
        }

        [IgnoreDataMember]
        [NonSerialized]
        private Dictionary<object, int> _itemLookup;

        [IgnoreDataMember]
        internal Dictionary<object, int> ItemLookup
        {
            get
            {
                return _itemLookup;
            }
            set
            {
                _itemLookup = value;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        private void ensureList()
        {
            if(InnerList == null)
            {
                InnerList = new List<T>(KeyedLoader);
                //_itemLookup = new Dictionary<object, int>();
            }
            if(ItemLookup == null)
            {
                _itemLookup = new Dictionary<object, int>();
            }

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        private void RefreshDictionary()
        {
            ensureList();
            for (int i = 0; i < this.ItemLookup.Count; i++)
            {
                ItemLookup = new Dictionary<object, int>();
                ItemLookup[InnerList[i]] = i;
            }
        }

        #region IList<T> Members

        public int IndexOf(T item)
        {
            ensureList();
            return InnerList.IndexOf(item);
        }

        public void Insert(int index, T item)
        {
            ensureList();
            InnerList.Insert(index, item);
            RefreshDictionary();

        }

        public void RemoveAt(int index)
        {
            ensureList();
            InnerList.RemoveAt(index);
            RefreshDictionary();

        }

        public T this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
                ensureList();
                return InnerList[index];
            }
            set
            {
                ensureList();
                InnerList[index] = value;
                ItemLookup[value] = index;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// ?Will throw an exception if the Key does not exist!
        /// </summary>
        public T this[object key]
        {
            get
            {
                ensureList();
                return InnerList[ItemLookup[key]];
            }
            set
            {
                ensureList();
                if (ItemLookup.ContainsKey(value))
                {
                    InnerList[ItemLookup[key]] = value;
                }
                else
                {

                    InnerList.Add( (T)Activator.CreateInstance( typeof(T) ) );
                    ItemLookup[key] = InnerList.Count-1;
                    // throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(string.Format("{0}", "Key"), 
                    //  "Key is not found in the dictionary cannot set value");
                }

            }

        }
        #endregion

        #region ICollection<T> Members

        public void Add(T item)
        {
            ensureList();
            InnerList.Add(item);
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            ensureList();
            InnerList.Clear();
        }

        public bool Contains(T item)
        {
            ensureList();
            return InnerList.Contains(item);
        }

        public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
        {
            ensureList();
            InnerList.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
        }

        public int Count
        {
            get { ensureList();  return InnerList.Count; }
        }

        public bool IsReadOnly
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public bool Remove(T item)
        {
            ensureList();
            bool retVal = InnerList.Remove(item);
            RefreshDictionary();
            return retVal;
        }

        #endregion

        #region IEnumerable<T> Members

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            ensureList();
            return InnerList.GetEnumerator();
        }

        #endregion

        #region IEnumerable Members

        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            ensureList();
            return InnerList.GetEnumerator();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do two objects have the same properties? If so, I recommend to you to use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/). It eliminates manual and tedious mapping from DTO to other models. You can install it using nuget by typing `Install-Package AutoMapper` in nuget package manager.

Comment: I thought about using that AutoMapper. I have Item.value as a property all the time coming to me - the only way I know what it belongs to ie parent (which ID changes each instance of the app) and what Child it is (which ID also changes at each instance of the app on creation of these initial items ).. is the KeyID class so I need to map item.value to DTO.Property where Item.KeyIDClass = DtoProperty and it has to be fast. So that if I have 2000 or 5000 items that are passed in the change event I can process them and the delegate can be done before the next event < 1second

Comment: List<DTO> dto , I need to map Item.value to dto[Parent].PropertyName where value is of a specific type and does match the property type if I map it correctly. Parent is a GUID - that is in the KeyID class along with the propertyname I need to map to. So I have keyID = item.KeyID. which contains the GUIDs and propertyname . If I use Automapper I think it uses reflection and I need to make it map the Index of the list by a changing GUID.

 but if there is a way to do it with Automapper I am open to using it. I used the internal dictionary in the list because of speed of lookups.

Comment: If that is the problem then you can use custom mapping. You can do it like this `AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Dto, Model>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Author,
               opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Author.Name));` or a like. Follow this [link](http://cpratt.co/using-automapper-creating-mappings/) and it will be explain to you every details about custom mapping.

Comment: I have been reading and looking at examples for Automapper - it seems the examples show collections to collections, but for me I have a single value of type(whatever was requested) that is returned to me. I have a list<DTO> which I need to find the individual DTO [where List<DTO>[keyedindex] = item.KeyID.Parent and set the property of that particular DTO [Where DTO.Property = item.KeyID.PropertyName to item.Value (of type whatever) . I also looked at DictionaryList but anything more than 10 items is bad.

Comment: I have decided to just use the dictionary setter as adding the additional librariy and learning the Automapper code introduces more complexity and more dependencies. What I have works and seems to be ok at least for now.